Connectivity issues with app using libp2p and QUIC in managed cloud environments
We are experiencing issues deploying the dockerized app in a simplified cloud-based environment. Here are the details for reference:

Docker image: gregorywhale/spy-with-params
Source code: GitHub Repository
Documentation: Official Docs

I have attempted deployment on several platforms, including Render, GCP: Cloud Run, and DigitalOcean AppPlatform. The app utilizes low-level networking with libp2p (uses QUIC) to connect to a P2P network.
In each cloud setup, I encountered connectivity errors while trying to bootstrap peers:
> ---On DigitalOcean AppPlatform 
WARN    failed to bootstrap  {"peer": "12D3KooWCW3LGUtkCVkHZmVSZHzL3C4WRKWfqAiJPz1NR7dT9Bxh", "error": "failed to dial: failed to dial 12D3KooWCW3LGUtkCVkHZmVSZHzL3C4WRKWfqAiJPz1NR7dT9Bxh: all dials failed\n  * [/ip4/63.32.166.181/udp/8999/quic-v1] timeout: no recent network activity"}
ERROR   wormhole-spy.root.p2p   p2p/p2p.go:215  failed to connect to bootstrap peer   {"peer": "{12D3KooWCW3LGUtkCVkHZmVSZHzL3C4WRKWfqAiJPz1NR7dT9Bxh: [/dns4/t-guardian-01.testnet.xlabs.xyz/udp/8999/quic-v1]}", "error": "failed to dial: failed to dial 12D3KooWCW3LGUtkCVkHZmVSZHzL3C4WRKWfqAiJPz1NR7dT9Bxh: all dials failed\n  * [/ip4/63.32.166.181/udp/8999/quic-v1] timeout: no recent network activity"}
ERROR   wormhole-spy.root.p2p   p2p/p2p.go:215  failed to connect to bootstrap peer   {"peer": "{12D3KooWJXA6goBCiWM8ucjzc4jVUBSqL9Rri6UpjHbkMPErz5zK: [/dns4/t-guardian-02.testnet.xlabs.xyz/udp/8999/quic-v1]}", "error": "failed to dial: failed to dial 12D3KooWJXA6goBCiWM8ucjzc4jVUBSqL9Rri6UpjHbkMPErz5zK: all dials failed\n  * [/ip4/176.34.174.72/udp/8999/quic-v1] timeout: no recent network activity"}
WARN    dht     go-libp2p-kad-dht@v0.25.2/dht.go:522    failed to bootstrap  {"peer": "12D3KooWJXA6goBCiWM8ucjzc4jVUBSqL9Rri6UpjHbkMPErz5zK", "error": "failed to dial: swarm closed"}

> ---On GCP: Cloud Run
WARN    swarm2  swarm/swarm_listen.go:30    listening failed    {"on": "/ip4/0.0.0.0/udp/8999/quic-v1", "error": "setting DF failed for both IPv4 and IPv6"}

I managed to set it up on a bare-metal Droplet on DigitalOcean, but this requires extra maintenance, which I would like to avoid.Has anyone encountered similar networking issues with these simplified cloud environments? I refer to them as "simplified" as opposed to a full Kubernetes setup, with which I am not familiar enough to create a complete infrastructure

QUIC requires non-trivial (end-to-end) changes by platform providers. Google Cloud permits HTTP/3 but you'll need to use and configure an HTTPS proxy for HTTP/3. I've not tried this with Cloud Run but it should work. I assume similar limitations exist with the other cloud providers.
